# How to render json message before returning from the function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I render a json message just before return?

With the following code, it returns after the last function is completed:

```
def create_company
    begin
      company = current_user.company
      result = company.create_users
      render(json: {message: result[0]}, status: :ok)
      company.send_email(result[1])
    rescue => e
      render(json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
   end
end
```

I expected to get the rendering result and then send an email, not waiting until the email to be sent in order to render the result.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Ruby returns implicitly, so the last item you put in the function will return. If you want it to return before return, you'll need to move `render(json: {message: result[0]}, status: :ok)` down one line after `company.send`

Comment: What are you trying to do?...render json and then send email?

Comment: You cannot just render json, you need to send the json object and show it on the view...is it a js request?

Comment: Why do you need the email to be sent _after_ the render? You'll need to setup a async service to do that, as controller methods need the return to be your rendered output

Comment: I want to do this just in this right order,
"render json and then send email" as you say Milind
The email take so long to send and I don't want do the front side to wait

Answer (score 1):

If this is a controller method, you'll want `render` to be the last thing you call, not `company.send`

```rb
def create_company
    begin
      company = current_user.company
      result = company.create_users
      company.send_email(result[1])
      render(json: {message: result[0]}, status: :ok)
    rescue => e
      render(json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
   end
end
```

**edit**
Based on your comments, I see that you want the email job to go out after the render happens. To do this, you'll need to setup an async service. Depending if you're using rails and what version, you can use [ActiveJob](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activejob). That in it's own right is a process to setup if you've never done it before, so you'll want to read up on it.

Your controller method would look like the following

```rb
def create_company
    begin
      company = current_user.company
      result = company.create_users
      company.send_email(result[1]).deliver_later
      render(json: {message: result[0]}, status: :ok)
    rescue => e
      render(json: { error: e.message }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
   end
end
```

`deliver_later` is an active job method that you can call when sending an email if you have active job configured.

Comment: I want to do this controller just in this order that i said
`render(json: {message: result[0]}, status: :ok`
and than
`company.send_email(result[1])`
do not want to make the front side to wait all emails be send and than render

Comment: @ToshiukHirahata Ruby's execution is not async like JavaScript. If you want the email to fire off after the render, you'll need to setup an async service to handle that.